# Issues with edge detection on image with sobel filter with Java's ConvolveOP

Tags: java, image, image-processing, edge-detection

I'm trying to use a sobel filter to do edge detection on a BufferedImage. But it seems like the Java filter system doesn't handle negative values in the image properly (while a manual implementation would just `abs()` them). Is is possible to avoid this issue without writing the whole filter manually?

Code:

```
    BufferedImage image, converted_image;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("image.png"));

        // convert image from ARGB to RGB
        BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);
        g.dispose();
        image = newImage;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.exit(1);
    }

    float sobel[] = {
            1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
            2.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f
    };

    BufferedImageOp sobelFilter = new ConvolveOp(new Kernel(3, 3, sobel));

    converted_image = sobelFilter.filter(image, null);

    try {
        ImageIO.write(converted_image, "png", new File("image2.png"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

Example image:

[image]

And the faulty edge detection. Note that while the filter should only handle vertical edges, it only handles `black | white` edges and not `white | black` ones.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it is a matter of display - the method uses the color you are going "into" left to right - so the black covers everything - use a color image on this
[image: Useful image]

I get this

[image: output]